# So I'm trying to answer this: Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere

Tags: python

How do I define `y` properly?

I've already tried explicitly putting `y == 0` inside and outside the `for` loop

```
def has_33(nums):

    for x in nums:

        if nums[0] != 3:
            y == 0

        if x == 3:
            y = index(x)

        if nums[y+1] == 3:
            return True

        else:
            return False
```

`has_33(1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3)` should return `true` for example

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using the list as the iterable, I would use a for loop with an index. This should simplify the logic a lot:

```
def has_double_3(nums):
    # Start at the second element, and look at indices i, i-1
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i - 1] == nums[i] and nums[i] == 3:
            # found two numbers in a row equal to 3
            return True

    # no match found return false
    return False
```

Comment: I think its because the answer lacks completeness; try adding `def func_name(name):` perhaps? BTW, i didn't downvote.

Comment: @Chris I'll add that I suppose

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to do this, try this:

```py
def has_33(nums):

    for x in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[x] == 3 and nums[x+1]==3:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Downvoted because you’ve run over the end of your array

Answer (score 1):

You can pair adjacent items in the list by zipping the list with itself but with an offset of 1, and return `True` if any of the pair of adjacent items are both equal to 3:

```
def has_33(nums):
    return any(a == b == 3 for a, b in zip(nums, nums[1:]))
```

`num[1:]` creates a copy of the list, however, so to avoid a memory complexity of *O(n)*, you can use `itertools.islice` to iterate over `nums` from index 1 instead:

```
from itertools import islice
def has_33(nums):
    return any(a == b == 3 for a, b in zip(nums, islice(nums, 1, None)))
```

Comment: Clever answer, but whats the memory complexity here? Can this solution be modified to avoid the creation of a second array?

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip` the list with a right-shifted version of itself and loop by pairs of adjacent numbers:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]):
        if x == y == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

For very large lists, as noted by @GZ0, you can use an iterator using `itertools.islice` instead of `l[1:]`:

```
from itertools import islice

def has_33(nums):
    for x, y in zip(nums, islice(nums, 1, None)):
        if x == y == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: As a side remark, `nums[1:]` creates a copy of the original list, which could be undesirable for large lists. In that case one can create an iterator using `islice` instead of making a copy.

Comment: Your edit still uses `num[1:]`, which creates a copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I solved this problem:

```
def has_33(*args):
for location,number in enumerate(args):
    if number ==3:
        place = location+1
        if args[place] == 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```